# Is 48 polyphony in a digital piano enough for playing most classical music pieces?

Tags: piano

I have bought a CASIO CDP-130 digital piano - unfortunately it has only 48 polyphony. I only love classical music and that´s what I want to play. Will it be enough for playing most classical pieces as piano solo?

Comment: The proposed duplicate directly addresses the CDP-130 is [this answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/53200/70803), which includes example videos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  A full-range arpeggio flourish with sustain pedal might run out of notes, but I don't think you'll find it a practical limitation.

Incidentally, be wary of polyphony numbers on electric keyboards.  48-polyphony might mean only 24 notes if a layered sound - piano/strings maybe - is selected.  Your CDP-130 can do this.  But I think you can expect 48 notes on a plain piano sound.

I investigated the new range of Casio pianos recently, in a search for something lighter to carry than my Kurzweil PC3X. (You just DON'T take your car to a central London gig any more, I need something I can carry on my back.)    I was most impressed by them, particularly considering Casio's previous reputation for being cheap-and-nasty and the low price.

Comment: St John's Wood is pretty good for parking after 6:30 pm . Did a couple of night shoots out of there last week, base right next to Lords, shoot in Marylebone… though I wouldn't have wanted to walk between the two with a piano on my back ;)) Might be worth a look at a black cab from/to there though, save worrying about getting home on the tube at midnight or after.

Comment: @tetsujin A book, a book!!! ;)